# Fairplay SPC request returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, fairplay

I'm attemping to use the [AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest streamingContentKeyRequestDataForApp:contentIdentifier:options:error:]; method to obtain an SPC key but I'm getting nil returned to me instead of the intended SPC value. I am mainly referencing the provided example Fairplay application. I'm using an encoded request URL host string as a content identifier and a .DER certificate retrieved from the SPC server as the app data. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

```
NSString *hostString = [URL host];  
NSData *assetId        = [NSData dataWithBytes:[hostString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] length:[hostString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
NSData *certificate = (obtained via Key Server).  

NSError *error;  
NSData *SPC = [loadingRequest streamingContentKeyRequestDataForApp:certificate contentIdentifier:assetId options:nil error:&error]
```

The output of SPC here is nil. The full  error description is as follows:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain  
Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed"   
UserInfo=0x170461980  
{NSUnderlyingError=0x1740548e0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12640.)",  
NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12640),  
NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the test stream was not correctly encrypted using SAMPLE-AES encryption.